# Threadpool and try catch to next after

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans, try-catch, threadpool

I am trying to make a thread pool that makes workers and jobs to be created and when they are busy it should not give jobs to them workers. I have this code so far however when i try to run it because i have 2 try and catch in worker.java run() it just wont output them in order. I want the first the first try to happen so that it shows all workers have started work and then i want it to say which worker started their jobs.

And if there is a way to use the busy = true; saying this worker is busy so give the job to next worker.

Worker.java

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {

    private final int id;  // Unique worker ID.

    private final JobStack jobStack;  // Reference to the job stack.
    private final ResourceStack resourceStack;  // Reference to the resource stack.

    private Job job;  // Job being processed.
    private Resource[] resources;  // Resources being used for job being processed.

    private boolean busy;  // Indicates the status of the worker. True when they are working (executing jobs) and false when there are no more jobs left to execute.

    private final Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> jobsCompleted;  // The job record of the worker. Stores each job's ID and the IDs of the resources used for each job.

    // Constructor.
    public Worker(int theId, JobStack theJobStack, ResourceStack theResourceStack) {
        id = theId;
        jobStack = theJobStack;
        resourceStack = theResourceStack;
        job = null;
        busy = true;
        jobsCompleted = new TreeMap<>();
    }

    public void run() {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Worker " + id + " started Work ");
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }    
        catch (Exception e)
        {            
            System.out.println ("Exception is caught");
        }

        for (Job job = jobStack.pop(); job != null; job = jobStack.pop()) {
            try{
                System.out.println("Worker " + id + " started Job "  + job.getId());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {            
                System.out.println ("Exception is caught");
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Workforce.java

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Workforce {

    private final Worker[] pool;  // The worker population.
    private int workerCount = 0;  // Used to generate each worker's ID and to keep a record of the number of workers in the workforce.

    Thread[] workerThreads;

    private final JobStack jobStack;  // Reference to the job stack.
    private final ResourceStack resourceStack;  // Reference to the resource stack.

    // Constructor.
    public Workforce(int size, JobStack theJobStack, ResourceStack theResourceStack) {
        jobStack = theJobStack;
        resourceStack = theResourceStack;

        pool = new Worker[size];
        for(int i=0; i<pool.length; i++) {
            pool[i] = new Worker(workerCount, jobStack, resourceStack);
            workerCount++;
        }

        workerThreads = new Thread[pool.length];
        for(int i=0; i<workerThreads.length; i++) {
            workerThreads[i] = new Thread(pool[i]);
        }
    }


    /// UNDER CONSTRUCTION /////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    // Starts all the worker threads.
    public void start() {

        for(int i=0; i<pool.length; i++) {
           workerThreads[i] = new Thread(pool[i]);           
            workerThreads[i].start();}
    }



    // Checks whether all workers have finished.
    public boolean allWorkersFinished() {

       return false;
    }
    // Prints the job record of all workers.
    public void printJobRecords() {
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pause your worker threads in-between your first and second try-catch blocks, and resume again when the manager finished the initialization. You can achieve this through `wait()/notify()` which are designed to block (release) a thread until (when) a specific condition is met.

Your design seems to me based on a *manager-worker (master-slave)* parallel architecture. 
The manager starts all workers at the beginning, and after that manager tells all the workers to start their working. On the workers side, after initialization, it immediately switches to the pause state and wait for the next command from the manager.

In a manager-worker model, typically, the manager maintains a work pool, a set of work items, and upon request, the manager sends the next available work item to a worker. Each worker processes one work item at one time and, when finished,
requests the manager for a new work item. This continues until there are no work items left. When all the work items are complete, the manager tells the workers to stop.

A possible solution would be sharing a common lock between manager and workers. After your first try-catch block, all workers call `wait()` on that lock, and manager calls `notifyAll()` on the same lock when all the workers are initialized.

```
final Object lock = new Object();
```

**Wroker**

```
boolean isWorking = false;

// your first try-catch block

synchronized (lock) {
    try {
        while (!isWorking) {
            lock.wait();
        }

        isWorking = true;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();            
    } 
}

// your second try-catch block

// do your work here!
```

**Manager**

```
// Starts all the worker threads.  

synchronized (lock) {
    lock.notifyAll(); // notify workers that initialization is done!
}
```